# getting error after updatet documentDB sdk .net to 1.10.0 or latest

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, azure-cosmosdb

I have a project and it was working ppropely but due to the older version of `Microsoft DocumentDB` I can't use all the query like between and etc. So, I have updated the packages.

Below is my current package version.

```
Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB : Version - 1.12.2
DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity : Version - 1.0.10-beta
```

Older Verion of Package.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client 0.9.0-preview
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0
```

Exception:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedResponse`1>
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.IDocumentQuery`1.ExecuteNextAsync()'.

Stacktrace:

> at DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity.UserStore`1.<GetUsers>d__9.MoveNext()
>
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
>   stateMachine)    at
>   DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity.UserStore`1.GetUsers(Expression`1
>   predicate)    at
>   DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity.UserStore`1.<FindByNameAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Cherish.Api.Controllers.LoginController.d__9.MoveNext()
>   in E:\Chandresh\MVC
>   Projects\Cherish\Experiment\Cherish.Api\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line
>   90

Code Snippet:

```
 var Client = new DocumentClient(new
 Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbEndpointUrl"]),
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbAuthKey"]);
 var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new
 UserStore<ApplicationUser>(Client, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentDbDatabaseName"], "UserDetail"));
```

Error Line:

```
await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
```

Comment: Your "Exception" text doesn't show anything useful, try to get exception type, text, inner exception etc.

Comment: Okay, Let me update the question

Comment: What kind project uses this NuGet package? library, web application, console,.. i'm assuming .NET Framework (not core) here..

Comment: MVC Web Application

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as answer that will help more communities who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the SDK compatibility issue. It seems that there is an [issue](https://github.com/tracker086/DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity/issues/27) that [DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity 1.0.10-beta SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity/) works with [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/1.9.5) : **Version >= 1.10**.

Please have a try to use the following 2 ways to resolve this issue.

1.If **downgrade**  Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB is possible, please use the [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/1.9.5) 1.9.5 version SDK in your other project.

2.Please have a try to download the [DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity](https://github.com/tracker086/DocumentDB.AspNet.Identity/tree/master/src) source code. And update  the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB version to the lastest(1.14.1) in the source code project. Then recompile to generate a new dll to reference in your other projects, then it should work perfectly. I have tested it on my side.